# The method setVerticalSpacing(int) is undefined for the type GridLayout

Tags: java, android, grid-layout, android-gridlayout

Why am I getting this error?  `The method setVerticalSpacing(int) is undefined for the type GridLayout`.  This method is made for GridLayout views.

Here is the declaration of my GridLayout:

```
GridLayout gameplayGL;
gameplayGL = new GridLayout(getApplicationContext());
gameplayGL.setVerticalSpacing(1);
gameplayGL.setHorizontalSpacing(1);  //same error here
```

This should be a routine method that I should be able to run on my gameplayGL layout.  I must be missing something obvious.  Why is this throwing an error?

Comment: I can't find that method in the docs. Could you provide a link to it?

Comment: Oops, that method is for GridView, not GridLayout.  My mistake, thanks anyways @csmckelvey!  Wish they had a method like that for GridLayout.